# What is the difference between Firmware v 1.3.7.2 and 4.0.0.07?

Tags: cisco, linksys

I got a RV042 (v1.2) and tried flashing 4.0.0.07; After some research I found out that the current firmware version is only flashable on v3 hardware.

1. Does anybody know what the difference is/where to find the changelog?
2. Also what's the difference between Harware v1.2 and v3?
3. Is it wise to get v3 + 4.0.0.07 instead? (I can still return the current one.)

Please advise :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/csbr/rv0xx/release/rv0xx_rn_v4-0-2-08.pdf) is a link to all the release notes for you to read yourself, but the main feature of v4.x is IPv6 support plus some bug-fixes.

As for differences, well I can't find any actual documentation but obviously v3 is more capable, such that it can support IPv6 etc. I doubt there's too much difference, presumably more CAM memory to hold the extra entries, and yes, if IPv6 is part of your infrastructure or roadmap then I'd go for the v3 hardware plus v4.x software combo.

Comment: +1 for the firmware release notes -_-